# DateTimePicker jumps back to current date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using a winform which contains 2 Datetimepicker(dtp1, dtp2) both are bound with following code

```
dtp1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "<database-field1>");
dtp2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "<database-field2>");
```

so the use case is that the user selects a date an hits the save button and the data should be saved in the database via stored procedure(sp) which is called on the button click event.

before the sp is called I set 2 DateTime variables an fill the variables with with following code

```
var1 = dtp1.Value;
var2 = dtp2.Value;
```

The problem I have is that if the user hits the save button dtp1 keeps the selected value but dtp2 as soon as the focus is not on dtp2 anymore the value sets back to the current date. Both controlls using the same code and both controls have the same settings I'm complete and totaly clueless and stuck with this problems now for houers.

@Shaharyar 
the click methode

```
DateTime var1, var2;

private void btn_WV_Anlegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var2 = dtp2.Value;
  var1 = dtp1.Value;

  using (var context = new project_entities())
  {
    context.sp_update_WV(var1, var2);
  }
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to any event handlers on `dtp2` that you aren't on `dtp1`?

Comment: show the code of your button click event.

Comment: @JMK no the settings are execty the same